# Log file extract data and append back same line

Tags: scripts, grep, awk

I have a snort.rule file, I need to extract cve numbers from the line and append them back in **msg** field of the same line inside flower brackets, below is the old log.

> ```
> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 1"; content:"miniupnpd/1."; fast_pattern:only; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*miniupnpd\/1\.[0-3]/mi"; reference:url/29/security -dont-play; reference: arch/Architecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2013-0229;sid:2016302; rev:5;)
> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 2"; content:"Intel SDK for UPnP devices"; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*Intel SDK for UPnP devices/mi"; reference: /infosec/blog/2013/01/29; reference:arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2012-5958; reference:cve,2012-5959;sid:2016303; rev:4;)
> ```

Required output,

> ```
> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 1 {cve,2013-0229}"; content:"miniupnpd/1."; fast_pattern:only; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*miniupnpd\/1\.[0-3]/mi"; reference:url/29/security -dont-play; reference: arch/Architecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2013-0229;sid:2016302; rev:5;)
> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 2 {cve,2012-5958 cve,2012-5959}"; content:"Intel SDK for UPnP devices"; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*Intel SDK for UPnP devices/mi"; reference: /infosec/blog/2013/01/29; reference: arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2012-5958; reference:cve,2012-5959;sid:2016303; rev:4;)
> ```

I am able to extract the CVE numbers, but appending back I am not getting

```
cat /tmp/snort.rule | grep -o -E -e 'sid:[^;]+' -e 'reference:cve,[^;]+'
```